# how to parse a double-quote delimited string that can contain escaped double quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I need to parse the line from the stream that would look like this: `command "string1" "string2"` string can contain spaces and escaped double-quotes. I need to split it so that I get command, string1 and string2 as array elements. I think split() with regex matching `"` but not `\"` ( `.split("(?<!\\\\)\"")`  ) would do the job, but I hear that that is not a good idea.

Is there any better way of doing this in Java?

Comment: This is not a free code writing service. Give it a try. If you can't get it to work, post what you have done and what is going wrong and we will try to help you.

Comment: Honestly, just do a split on blanks and then parse the command arguments separately. You don't have to mess with regex for that

Comment: @Dici I can't split on blanks because arguments can contain blanks

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm not asking for code, I'm asking is there a better way of doing this

Comment: @user1902247 updated answer, guided my rici

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like that should do the trick, assuming you want to remove the external double quotes when applicable (if you don't, it's just a matter of changing the first capturing group to also include the quotes):

```
public class Demo {
    private static final Pattern WORD = 
        Pattern.compile("\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*)\"|([^\\s\"]+)");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  cmd = 
           "command "                                  +
           "\"string with blanks\" "                   +
           "\"anotherStringBetweenQuotes\" "           +
           "\"a string with \\\"escaped\\\" quotes\" " + 
           "stringWithoutBlanks";

        Matcher matcher = WORD.matcher(cmd);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String capturedGroup = matcher.group(1) != null ? matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2);
            System.out.println("Matched: " + capturedGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Matched: command
Matched: string with blanks
Matched: anotherStringBetweenQuotes
Matched: a string with \"escaped\" quotes
Matched: stringWithoutBlanks
```

The regex is a bit complicated, so it well deserves a bit of explanation:

- `[^\\\\\"]` matches everything but a backslash or double quotes
- `\\\\.` matches a backslash followed by any character (including double quotes), namely escaped characters
- `(?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*` matches any sequence of escaped or non-escaped characters, but without capturing the group (because of the `(?:)`)
- `"\"((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*)\"` matches any such sequence wrapped into double quotes and captures the inside of the quotes
- `([^\\s\"]+)` matches any non-empty sequence of non-blank characters, and captures it in a group

Comment: Thanks and sorry to bother you, but whats the advantage of this approach over `str.split("(?<!\\\\)\"")` ?

Comment: You don't bother me, I'm here to answer questions. The advantage is that the regex is much clearer to me. If you wanted to split, your regex would have to describe the separators whereas my regex describe what you actually want to capture. This also means that my regex can perform some checks on the inputs. Finally, my approach enables to match the string lazily rather than allocate an array for the entire match. This will make little difference in most cases but it can be a good thing if the string is really large

Comment: @dici: i didn't dv, but whoever did probably did so because it doesn't work. Try it on an input like the one in the OP which has two distinct double-quoted substrings. And it doesn't handle escaped quotes, although that only matters when you fix the first problem.

Comment: @rici depends what you expect as an output. It matches my expectation, it does not match yours, does it match the one from the OP ? It's not really specified in the OP, so I'm curious how you understood the requirements

Comment: I understand the requirements to be that `command "string1" "string2"` is broken into three parts. That seems quite explicit. Afaics your program would break it into only two parts. (I didn't try it, so if I'm wrong, feel free to demonstrate my error.) There also seems to be the expectation that the quotes are removed but that is not explicit.

Comment: @rici ups, I do have a bug, I'll try and fix it, thanks

Comment: @rici fixed, good spot. I wanted to demonstrate it could parse both strings within quotes and without quotes, but it actually hid my bug :p. About the removal of the quotes, I agree, I hesitated on that. This would be easy to change by adding capturing groups

Comment: @rici added a snippet to unquote the args. There might be a cleaner way to do it, I take suggestions if you have any

Comment: Right. Now it doesn't handle escaped quotes, as i mentioned. Try `"\"([^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*\"|[^\\s\"]+"`. Warning: untried, might be escaping errors.

Comment: @rici think it won't work without a look-behind. I'll try with this

Comment: If you try to use look behind you'll most likely get it wrong, because you need to distinguish between `\"` (an escaped quote), `\\"` (an escaped backslash followed by a quote which ends the string, `\\\"` (an escaped backslash followed by an escaped quote), and etc. Getting these wrong is a very common bug.  My solution actually works; I'm just not sure that I escaped everything correctly for Java strings and regexes.

Comment: @rici you're right about the lookbehind. Your solution was missing some capturing groups to fit in my existing code

Comment: If the input may also contain escaped backslashes this approach won't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you give an example of what you think would not work (input + expectation) ?

Comment: A string like `word \"string"`. Perhaps, this type of input is not expected.

Comment: I don't think this is even valid, since you have an escaped double quote character and and un-matched double quote character. Did you mean `word \\"string"` (which I think is not a valid input) ?